# Erro ao tentar extrair tabela de um site pelo R, como resolver?

Tags: html, r, xml, url, rvest

Estou usando esse código, quero importar a tabela dos países para o R:

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population"
country_data <- readHTMLTable(url, which=2)
```

O R retorna o erro:

```
Error: failed to load external entity "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population"
```

Como proceder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minha pouca experiência com web scraping no `R` me fez gostar mais do pacote `rvest` do que do `XML` para fazer este tipo de trabalho. Por isso, vou te passar uma solução com ele, em vez de uma solução com o pacote que tu queria:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population"

tabela <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE) %>%
  .[[2]]
```

O único truque aqui é saber identificar a posição da tabela que te interessa dentro daquilo que foi baixado da internet. No caso específico do endereço presente no objeto `url`, a tabela que nos interessa está na posição `[[2]]`.

Até onde sei, a única maneira de descobrir o número correto é por tentativa e erro. Talvez haja outra forma, mas eu desconheço.

---

Caso o código acima gere o erro `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached`, tente rodar o comando abaixo:

```
library(rvest)
library(curl)

url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population"

tabela <- read_html(curl(url, handle = curl::new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))) %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE) %>%
  .[[2]]
```

Ao usar o `curl`, nós forçamos o scraper a se identificar ao site. Assim, o site não refuta a conexão que o `R` tenta fazer.

Comment: Quando eu uso esse comando, aparece esse erro: Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached

Comment: Tente o código novo, abaixo da linha horizontal.

Comment: O erro persiste, isso pode ter a ver com minha atual versão do R? 3.3.0, quando os pacotes foram feitos na 3.3.2?

Comment: Talvez. Eu testei ambos os códigos no R 3.3.2, no Mac e no Linux, e funcionou em ambos. Atualiza o R e tenta de novo.

Comment: Testei na minha casa na versão 3.3.0 e funcionou direitinho. Acredito que seja algo relacionado a firewall, mas não sei resolver.

Comment: Infelizmente, sem poder reproduzir exatamente as condições do local onde o código não funcionou, eu não tenho como te ajudar. Por isso, dado que minha resposta funcionou, tu poderia aceitá-la? Assim, as pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida no futuro vão saber que esta resposta está correta e responde à pergunta realizada.

Comment: Eu não sabia como fazer isso, mas já aceita, valeu amigo!